# get all elements contain attributes from a namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I wish to get all elements that contain attributes from namespace http://www.my.com/

The code:

```
   IEnumerable<XElement> list1 =
                    from el in RootElement.DescendantsAndSelf()
                    //where it contains attributes from http://www.my.com/ - how?
                    select el;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify [namespace part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.namespace.aspx) of attribute name:

```
XNamespace my = "http://www.my.com/";
IEnumerable<XElement> list1 =
        from el in xdoc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf()
        where el.Attributes().Any(attr => attr.Name.Namespace == my)
        select el;
```